# UITextfield UIDatePicker inputView very dark

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uicolor

I have a `UITextField` that needs to show a `UIDatePicker` with a `UIToolbar` in above to close it.
I set the `UIDatePicker` to the textfield's `inputView`, and the `UIToolbar` to the `inputAccessoryView`.

This works fine, but by default i get weird color effects.  The `inputAccessoryView` is translucent as one would expect from iOS7, however the `inputView` appears to have a black background behind it that is then made translucent.  This leaves it with the `inputView` much grayer when the background color is set to the same as it is in the `inputAccessoryView`.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [self.someTextField setInputView:datePicker];

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    pickerToolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:nil];
    pickerToolbar.items = @[doneButton];
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    self.someTextField.inputAccessoryView = pickerToolbar;
}
```

This results in an image like this (with the main view's background colors set in InterfaceBuilder):
[image: Example with clearColor]

You can see the red and green showing through both, but the `UIDatePicker` is much darker.

If I change both from `clearColor` to `whiteColor`, I get this:
[image: Example with whiteColor]

Here you can see the `inputAccessoryView` is still translucent (though less so), but the `inputView` is pure white.  If it is translucent it is a LOT less, and I can't see it anymore.

How can i make them both transparent?  As is, difficult without just making both entirely opaque.  I want to keep them translucent to follow iOS7 guidelines, but not if it will give me that muddy dark version like in the first screenshot.